# Coldfusion, jquery and sending a file using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cffile

I'm trying to send file using jquery ajax method, and I don't know how to receive it in Coldfusion, convert it in proper file object, and finally, save it on server in Media folder.

There is something I want:

```
var myDocument = $('#fileinput').prop('files');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('myDocument', myDocument);

   $.ajax({
        url: "./somePath/file.cfc?method=handleDocument",
        type: "POST", 
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result,status,xhr){
            doSomething();
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error){
            doSomethingElse();
        }
    });
```

Now, we are in **./somePath/file.cfc** trying to fetch **myDocument** object and save it:

```
<cffunction name="handleDocument" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" returntype="string">

        <cfset requestData = GetHttpRequestData()>
        <cfset content = requestData.content>
        <cfset anyExtesion= content.getExtension()>
        <!---There's no such method getExtension(), but I need something like that--->
  
        
        <cffile action="write" file="./Media/myDocument.#anyExtesion#" output="#x.content#"/>
    

       <cfreturn "File is saved in Media folder.">
</cffunction>
```

Comment: What do `<cfdump var="#requestData#">` and `<cfdump var="#FORM#">`give you? Also, have you looked at `<cffile action="upload">` ([Adobe docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-upload.html))?

Comment: (You might have to switch your `<cffunction>` to `output="yes"` and remove the `<cfreturn>` to actually see the dump in the response.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to manually parse the raw http request data to extract the file information. CFFile handles it for you:

- Single file: [cffile action="upload"](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-upload.html)
  and [FileUpload()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/fileupload.html) <sup>**</sup>
- Multiple files: [cffile action="uploadAll"](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-uploadall.html) and [FileUploadAll()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/fileuploadall.html) <sup>**</sup>

  <sub>** *The term 'upload' in the tag/function names is a misnomer. They handle low level i/o tasks for files already uploaded to the server*</sub>

#### cffile action="upload"

Single file uploads require the *name* of the form field containing the file to be uploaded. To avoid hard-coding a static value, make it an `argument` to the cffunction instead. Use the `result` variable to return details about the uploaded file as a structure  (See [CFFile - Usage Section](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-upload.html) for a list of the available properties).

Here's a starter example that allows uploading of a .PNG or .JPG file (any other extension throws an exception). A status structure is returned as json, if successful.

```
<cfcomponent>   
    <cffunction name="handleDocument" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="false">
        <cfargument name="fileFieldName" type="string" required="true">
        
        <!--- demo - only allow JPG files  --->
        <cffile action="upload"
                destination="c:/nonwebaccessbile/path"
                fileField="#arguments.fileFieldName#"               
                nameconflict="MakeUnique" 
                strict="true"
                result="local.result"
                allowedExtensions=".png,.jpg"
        >
        
        <!--- for demo return saved file name  --->
        <cfreturn {
            "fileWasSaved": local.result.fileWasSaved 
            , "serverFile": local.result.serverFile 
        } >
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

#### JavaScript

> var myDocument = $('#fileinput').prop('files');

One correction to the js code. The above returns a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object, not a file. To access the first [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) in the list, use `$('#fileinput').prop('files')[0]` instead.

Then since the cffunction requires a field *name*, append that value to the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object before the ajax call:

```
var theFileField = $("#fileinput");
var theFieldName = theFileField.prop("name")
var theFirstFile = theFileField.prop("files")[0];

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileFieldName', theFieldName);
formData.append(theFieldName, theFirstFile);

$.ajax({
    url: "./pathto/file.cfc?method=handleDocument",
    type: "POST", 
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json", 
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
}).done(function(response, status, xhr){
    // do stuff here ... 
}).fail(function(xhr,status,error){
    // do stuff here ... 
});
```

#### Security

File uploads can pose a BIG security risk to web apps. Before putting ANY file uploads into production, read up on how to secure them first. A few good resources:

- [CFML SecureUpload CFC (Github)](https://github.com/foundeo/cfml-security/tree/master/secureupload)
- [Securing ColdFusion Apps 2021 (see "File Uploads" page 63)](https://www.petefreitag.com/presentations/cfsummit/2021/2021-06-securing-coldfusion-apps.pdf)
- [OWASP - File Upload Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/File_Upload_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Comment: Is there a trick to getting this to work in a CFC file? I've tried using the code above, but it always errors out. Putting similar code into a CFM file and POSTing to that works, and that's probably what I'll have to live with, but it's driving me nuts trying to figure out why it hates CFCs.